# Асинхронная фильтрация списка строк

Tags: python, циклы, асинхронность, asyncio

```
filtered_strings = [string for string in need_strings if string not in all_strings]
```

Есть такая строка. Она находится внутри асинхронного метода и при выполнении останавливает все остальные асинхронные методы, потому что выполняется не асинхронно. Как сделать, чтобы эта фильтрация не останавливала работу всего остального скрипта? Список all_string очень большой.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить фильтрацию в другом потоке или процессе.

Comment: Процесс пул экзекутор

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать конструкцию `async for`:

```py
filtered_strings = [string async for string in need_strings if string not in all_strings]
#                          ^^^^^
```

Comment: Если need_strings - не асинхронный итератор или итерируемый объект, это работать не будет, будет падать с ошибкой вида `TypeError: 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method`